# Determine the adjoint of $\tilde Q(x)$ for $\tilde Q(x)u:=(Qu)(x)$ where $Q:U→L^2(Ω,ℝ^d$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and $U$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $H:=L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$
- $U$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $Q:U\to H$ be a [Hilbert-Schmidt Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator)

It's easy to see that for $\lambda$-almost all $x\in\Omega$ $$\tilde Q(x)u:=(Qu)(x)\;\;\;\text{for }u\in U$$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt Operator from $U$ to $\mathbb R^d$, since $$\int_\Omega\left\|\tilde Q(x)\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\:\mathbb R^d)}^2\;{\rm d}\lambda(x)=\left\|Q\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\:H)}^2<\infty\;.\tag 1$$

> How can we determine the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces) ${\tilde Q(x)}^\ast$ of $\tilde Q(x)$? In particular, how can we calculate $\tilde Q(x){\tilde Q(x)}^\ast e_i$ for the $i$th standard basis vector $e_i$ of $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: it means nothing to me. make things simple, nobody cares $Q$ is HS, it won't change anything that it is compact

Comment: @user1952009 The question is short. How can I further simplify it? Maybe it helps you, if you know my motivation: I've hoped that the special form of $\tilde Q$ would help me in [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873799/can-we-write-texttrqx-nabla2uxqx-for-u%e2%88%88c2%e2%84%9dd-and-q%e2%84%9dd%e2%86%92-te).

Comment: what is $(Qu)(x)$ and $\tilde{Q}(x)u$ ? you know that $h \mapsto h(x)$ isn't a bounded operator ? but if you replace $x$ by ... then $h \mapsto h(x)$ becomes bounded and $\tilde{Q}$ is simply $Q^*$

Comment: so no I don't want to help you if you make no efforts  : make your questions clear

Comment: @user1952009 $Q$ is a given HS-operator from $U$ to $H=L^2(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ and hence $Qu$ is a function in $H$.

Comment: $\tilde{Q}$ is $Q^*$, it is obvious

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't ask for $Q^*$ but for $\tilde Q(x)^*$.

Comment: make your question clear (because at this point you don't understand your own question)

Comment: @user1952009 I think that the question *is* clear and I don't understand why you think that I don't understand it. Could you make your point clear?

Comment: for some $x \in [0,1]$, consider the operator $T_x : L^2([0,1]) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, $\ f \mapsto \langle f, \delta_x \rangle$. what can you say on it ?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see the relation to the question. $T_x$ is neither a possible choice for $Q$ nor for $\tilde Q(x)$.

Comment: that's what I say since 2 months : make your questions clear, find an example, and see what happens. So take $U = H = L^2([0,1])$ what is your example for $Q$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 The question is motivated by [a question about a stochastic Navier-Stokes equation](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244884/recast-a-finite-dimensional-multiparameter-sde-as-an-infinite-dimensional-sde) with noise controlled by some function $\xi:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d\to\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$. I'm not sure how I should choose $\xi$ in practice. In the context of this question $\xi$ is independent of time and $\xi=\tilde Q$. So, one possible choice I've got in mind for $Q$ could be $U=H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $Qu:=(b\cdot\nabla)u+cu$ for some $b,c\in H$.

Comment: bad example, too complicated, choose a much simpler one (you'll see that here $x$ isn't a point of $\Omega$ but a distribution on $\Omega$, i.e. an unbounded operator $H \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, that's why I wrote $\delta_x$ a few lines above)

Comment: @user1952009 What $x$ are you talking about? Please give me a better example.

Comment: in functional analysis, the map $L^2([0,1]) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, $f \mapsto f(x)$ is written $f \mapsto \langle f, \delta_x \rangle$, i.e. it is an unbounded operator $L^2([0,1]) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ identified with the distribution on $[0,1]$ : $\ \ \delta_x$

Comment: so $Q(u)(x) = \tilde{Q}(x)(u)$ for every $u \in L^2([0,1]), x \in [0,1]$ is written $\langle Q u, \delta_x \rangle= \langle u, \tilde{Q}\delta_x\rangle$ for every $u \in L^2([0,1]), x \in [0,1]$, i.e. $\tilde{Q} = Q^*$ (because in some sense the $\delta_x, x \in [0,1]$ are dense in $L^2([0,1])^*$)

Comment: In general, $Q\in\operatorname{HS}(U,H)$ and $\tilde Q:\mathbb R^d\to\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$. $\tilde Q$ doesn't need to be linear and hence it makes no sense to talk about its adjoint. But even when $\tilde Q$ is linear, the adjoint $Q^\ast$ of $Q$ is a mapping $H\to U$. And since  $\tilde Q$ is a mapping $\mathbb R^d\to\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$, it's not possible that $\tilde Q=Q^\ast$, cause $\tilde Q$ and $Q^\ast$ are totally different objects.

Comment: @user1952009 Let's consider the simple example $\Omega=(0,1)$, $U=H=L^2(\Omega)$ and $$(Qu)(x):=\int_\Omega 1_{(0,\:x]}u\;{\rm d\lambda}\;\;\;\text{or }u\in U\text{ and }x\in\Omega\;.$$ Then, $Q\in\operatorname{HS}(U,H)$ and $$\langle Qu,v\rangle_H=\langle u,Q^\ast v\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\text{ and }v\in H$$ with $$(Q^\ast v)(y)=\int_\Omega 1_{[y,\:1)}v\;{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }v\in H\text{ and }y\in\Omega\;.$$ But as I said before, it doesn't make sense to try to prove that $\tilde Q=Q^\ast$. What do you say here?

Comment: $(Qu)(x) = \int_0^1 1_{t < x} u(t) dt$ so $\langle Q u,v \rangle = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1_{t < x} u(t)  dt   v(x)  dx = \langle  u,Q^* v \rangle$ with $(Q^*v)(t) = \int_0^1 1_{x > t} v(x)  dx $ and $(Qu)(y) = \langle Qu, \delta_y \rangle = \langle u, Q^* \delta_y \rangle$ where $(Q^* \delta_y)(x) = 1_{x < y} $ i.e. $(Qu)(x)  = \tilde{Q}(y)(u) = \int_0^1 \tilde{Q}(y)(x) u(x) dx$ where $ \tilde{Q}(y) = 1_{x < y}$. There is nothing else to say, and of course the adjoint of $\langle., 1_{x < y} \rangle$ is $\langle 1_{x < y} , .\rangle$

Comment: @user1952009 What is $\delta_y$ when used in the expression $(Q^\ast\delta_y)(x)$? The function $\delta_y(x):=1_{\left\{y\right\}}(x)$ for $x\in\Omega$?

Comment: $\delta_y$ is the Dirac delta at $y$, it is a distribution, that why $u \mapsto u(y)$ is the unbounded operator $u \mapsto \langle u, \delta_y \rangle$

Comment: and there is a typo, I meant of course $(Qu)(y) = \tilde{Q}(y)(u)$ (where the point is that $\tilde{Q}(y) = Q^*(\delta_y)$ ...)

Comment: @user1952009 Then your $\delta_y$ is not an element of $H=L^2(\Omega)$ and hence $Q^\ast\delta_y$ is not defined. Listen, I don't understand what you're trying to show me. Please try it in a way which doesn't involve any distribution theory. We don't need that here.

Comment: lol... as I wrote there is nothing else to say, and in the basic example I didn't use the distribution theory (since $Q^* \delta_y$ is well-defined as you saw), but you need to understand that distributions are just densely defined unbounded operators from $L^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: and that in functional analysis, $u \mapsto u(x)$ is written $u \mapsto \langle u, \delta_x \rangle$

Comment: as I wrote in my 1st comment : what you need is making your question clear, because there is no other question here except what I wrote

Comment: @user1952009 The question is: What is the adjoint of $\tilde Q(x)$? Since $\tilde Q(x)$ is a mapping $U\to\mathbb R^d$, its adjoint must be a mapping $\mathbb R^d\to U$. How could that be any clearer? Forget about the Dirac delta function. This question should be answerable with pure operator theory.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, see the example

Comment: @user1952009 What? $\tilde Q(x)$ is for ($\lambda$-almost) all $x\in\Omega$ a bounded, linear operator from $U$ to $\mathbb R^d$. So, it makes *perfectly* sense to talk about its adjoint.

Comment: no, try again with the example

Comment: @user1952009 I don't need to consider any example. Again, fix $x\in\Omega$. Then $\tilde Q(x)$ is a bounded, linear operator from $U$ to $\mathbb R^d$. And each such operator has a adjoint just by definition.

Comment: no sense, what with the example ?

Comment: @user1952009 What exactly doesn't make sense in your opinion? The definition of $\tilde Q$ or that $\tilde Q(x)$, for any $x\in\Omega$, has an adjoint? [And if you man your example $f\mapsto\langle f,\delta_x$, that is an unbounded operator (as you say) and hence is neither an example for $Q$ nor for $\tilde Q$ or $\tilde Q(x)$].

Comment: write everything explicitly when $Q$ is as in the example... (take an example and see what happens !!!!)

Comment: bye ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user1952009 Consider my example for $Q$. I've showed you that $$(Q^\ast v)(y)=\int_\Omega 1_{[y,\:1)}v\;{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }v\in H\text{ and }y\in\Omega\;.$$ Moreover, $$\tilde Q(x)u=\int_\Omega 1_{(0,\:x]}u\;{\rm d\lambda}\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\text{ and }x\in\Omega$$ is well-defined. Fix $x\in\Omega$. The adjoint of $\tilde Q(x)$ is $$\tilde Q(x)^\ast y=1_{(0,x]}y\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in\Omega\;.$$ Everything is well-defined and makes perfectly sense. So, where do you think there is a problem?

Comment: @user1952009 What is your problem? I "discovered" nothing. You say that something (and you didn't tell me *what*) "doesn't make sense". That's why I gave you a complete example for what you can see that *everything* makes perfectly sense.

Comment: the adjoint of $T : H \mapsto \mathbb{C}, \ \ u \mapsto \langle u,v \rangle$ is $T^* :  \mathbb{C} \mapsto H^*, \ \ c \mapsto c\langle .,v \rangle$ it is of NO INTEREST

Comment: YOUR PROBLEM is that you don't understand the very basic concepts, because you never try with simple examples and see what happens

Comment: (and stop reading abstract courses)

Comment: @user1952009 But isn't that exactly what I've done? I've taken a simple example and saw what happens. And what should I say, it gave me no further insight at all. Please, just tell me why you think that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: no, it is what I have done, you asked a non-sense abstract question

Comment: the question is non-sense : "what is the adjoint of $u \mapsto \langle u,v\rangle$"

Comment: and there is no $\mathbb{R}^d$ here

Comment: ($\Omega$ isn't a vector space..)

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't ask for the adjoint of "$u\mapsto\langle u,v\rangle$". Could you please be less offensive and more concrete? Why is the question "nonsense"? It doesn't matter that $\Omega$ is no vector space. Why should it matter? $Q$ is an operator $U\to H$ and for each $x\in\Omega$, we have an operator $\tilde Q(x):U\to\mathbb R^d$. No one has said that the dependence $\Omega\ni x\mapsto\tilde Q(x)$ is an operator (and *that* would indeed make no sense). Is that something you've misunderstood?

Comment: lol... can YOU be more concrete, no you don't have an operator $U \to \mathbb{R}^d$ (and I'm not offensive, you are, since you don't want to understand that you don't understand what you wrote)

Comment: @user1952009 What should $\tilde Q(x)$ be else? It is obviously linear and bounded by $(1)$. And again, I emphasize that I don't mean $x\mapsto\tilde Q(x)$ with $\tilde Q(x)$ but the mapping $u\mapsto\tilde Q(x)u$ which is obviously an operator $U\to\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: ok, you should read again everything, and think "all the answers are there"

Comment: @user1952009 Why don't you simply tell me what exactly is wrong with my question? For example, you say "you don't have an operator $U\to\mathbb R^d$". What else is then $\tilde Q(x)$ in your opinion? Please just give an answer to that question.

Comment: come on, I showed you what is $\tilde{Q}(x)$ since the beginning : $\tilde{Q}(x) = \langle ., Q^* \delta_x\rangle$

Comment: @user1952009 Are you able to argue without $\delta_x$? Besides that, let me ask again, what is "$\tilde{Q}(x) = \langle ., Q^* \delta_x\rangle$" if not an operator $U\to\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: $Q$ is an operator $U \to L^2(\Omega)$ so $Q^* : L^2(\Omega) \to U$, so with $x \in \Omega$, $\delta_x $ is a distribution over $\Omega $, and $Q^* \delta_x$  is a distribution over $U$. hence $u \mapsto \langle u, Q^* \delta_x \rangle$ is an (unbounded) operator $U \to \mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ if $U$ is a real Hilbert space)

Comment: @user1952009 Why should we consider "$u\mapsto\langle u,Q^\ast\delta_x\rangle$"? I can't see any relation to the question. Please try to argue without $\delta_x$. As I've written in one of my comments, we should be able to handle the question without any knowledge of distribution theory.

Comment: now stop, and work

Comment: @user1952009 (1) I've reread everything as you suggested. However, I still don't get your point. If you really want to help me, then forget about your example with $\delta_x$. It's amazing that in functional analysis "$f↦f(x)$ is written $〈f,\delta_x〉$", but this fancy notation doesn't help here at all. So, let's stick to the very [definition of the adjoint in Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces).

Comment: @user1952009 Let's assume $Q$ is just a bounded, linear operator $U\to H=L^2(Ω,ℝ^d)$ such that $\tilde Q(x)$ is a bounded, linear operator $U→ℝ^d$. I'm interested in $\tilde Q(x)^*$ (for a fixed $x∈Ω$). By definition, $$〈u,\tilde Q(x)^*u⋅y〉_U=\tilde Q(x)u⋅y\;\;\;\text{for all }(u,x,y)∈U×ℝ^d×ℝ^d\;.\tag 2$$ Maybe it helps to observe that that means $$〈Qu,f〉_H=\int_Ω\tilde Q(x)u⋅f(x)\;{\rm d}λ(x)=\int_Ω〈u,\tilde Q(x)^*f(x)〉_U\;{\rm d}λ(x)\;.\tag 3$$ Please try to respond to what I've written in *this* comment.

Comment: @user1952009 You usually don't respond to my specific question and that's why we've written more than 50 comments without proceeding. (2) If you still think that the question for the adjoint of $\tilde Q(x)$ "doesn't make sense", then please show me that on my example with $Ω=(0,1)$, $U=H=L^2(Ω)$ and $$(Qu)(x):=\int_Ω1_{(0,\:x]}u\;{\rm dλ}\;\;\;\text{or }u∈U\text{ and }x∈Ω\;.$$ I've showed you what $\tilde Q(x)^*$ (for a fixed $x∈Ω$) is and what $Q^*$ is. So, if you see there a problem, please tell me.

Comment: @user1952009 (I've forgotten to mention that we obtain $$\langle u,Q^\ast f\rangle_U=〈u,\int_Ω\tilde Q(x)^*f(x)\;{\rm d}λ(x)〉_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\text{ and }f\in H\tag 4$$ from $(3)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Just curious... Your eq (2) seems to be 
\begin{align*}
\left\langle u,\widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)^{*}y\right\rangle _{U} & =\left\langle \widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)u,y\right\rangle _{\mathbb{R}^{d}},
\end{align*}
for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and $u\in U$.

Fix $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and choose an ONB $\left\{ \varphi_{j}\right\} $
in $U$. (I'm going to assume $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle $
is linear in the second variable.) Then 
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)^{*}y & =\sum_{j}\left\langle \varphi_{j},\widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)^{*}y\right\rangle _{U}\varphi_{j}=\sum_{j}\left\langle \widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)\varphi_{j},y\right\rangle _{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\varphi_{j}.
\end{align*}
So this gives 
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)^{*} & =\sum_{j}\left|\varphi_{j}\left\rangle \right\langle \widetilde{Q}\left(x\right)\varphi_{j}\right|=\sum_{j}\left|\varphi_{j}\left\rangle \right\langle \left(Q\varphi_{j}\right)\left(x\right)\right|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Clearly, there was a typo in $(2)$ and the equation should be as you wrote.

Comment: I don't understand the notation in your last equation.

Comment: The last line is a notation for rank-1 operators. So $\left|\varphi_{j}\left\rangle \right\langle \left(Q\varphi_{j}\right)\left(x\right)\right|:\mathbb{R}^{d}\longrightarrow U$,
by 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}^{d} & \in y\longmapsto\left\langle \left(Q\varphi_{j}\right)\left(x\right),y\right\rangle \varphi_{j}\in U.
\end{align*}